# What files do I need to move for zsh + oh-my-zsh if I migrate to a new machine?

Tags: macos, git, zsh, oh-my-zsh

New machine and I went looking for instructions for this and didn't find any. I'm sure I need to move over my `.zprofile` and `.zshrc`, anything else? I have the old machine still.

Bonus: also using `oh-my-zsh` and have a custom git prompt on the old machine, I'd rather not have to recreate that from scratch.

OSX, but any instructions for posix machines should apply.

Comment: Check the list at [Zsh/Bash startup files loading order (.bashrc, .zshrc etc.) | The Lumber Room](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/)

Comment: That's a hell of a link.

Answer (score 1):

The standard files you should copy from the user directory would be these (based on the great resource provided by DavidPostill in a comment):

- `~/.zshenv`
- `~/.zprofile`
- `~/.zshrc`
- `~/.zlogin`
- `~/.zlogout`

If you want more detail about these `zsh` files there is a brief explanation here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71258

For *Oh-My-Zsh* I can only add that you copy/replace `~/.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh`, based on my installation. `~/.zshrc` should mostly contain the rest of the *Oh-My-Zsh* customization you are relying upon, including the one for the git prompt, or maybe you have a file like `~/.git-prompt.sh`, if that's the case that one should be copied to the new machine too.

Comment: Good answer from a totally new person, well done